# What is the best approach for validating and storing complex multipage forms?

Tags: php, database, forms

I'm developing on a really bad code-base that is *loosely* formed around Zend Framework (PHP) so ORMs can't be used and neither can any other framework. I have attempted using Zend_Form but I found the documentation too sparse (I have developed small forms with Zend_Form but nothing of this size).

I need to create a long form (6 pages long). The user will be able to switch between each step as they please with no validation at all until they attempt to submit the form (not a good idea in my opinion but that's what the spec says).

At the end of the process, the form will be validated and then the data will be split into a number of different tables in the database. Oh and just to make things fun: there are three versions of this form, all with slight alterations on fields, nothing major. They all store the data in the same tables.

So, what's the best way to go about doing this? How should I structure it and what would you do if you had to build such a form? I'm writing it in PHP but would like to hear responses from programmers of other languages too. Also if there are any libraries or tools for building such forms, I'd like to hear those as well.

Comment: Are you asking just about the last part of the form submission?

Comment: I'm asking about the entire process from start to finish. I'm not asking for specific code samples, but merely an overview of where you would start, what classes you would create, etc. I have a working copy of the form currently as I had to rush it to meet a deadline, however now that I have more time I wish to recode it properly.

Comment: U mean u need the complete form creation and updating process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never done this using ZF, never done such form with validations only when submitting last step, never done a multistep form where user can jump from step to step as they want (I mean jumping from 1st step to 4th, e.g.).

What I did was a 5 step form (where there could be more 3 substeps within 4th step). User can follow the steps one step at a time or go back one step at a time. Each step is submitted and validated - until it is valid user cannot jump to the next step but he still can go back - the values inserted are stored within session. I have created a model (structured class containing other subclasses) so after each step is submitted and valid the data is set into this model that is stored within session.

If You need a really big form where user can jump through steps as he wants, I would consider two ways:

1. Create just one form with steps visually divided into a tabs - each tab will contain only related fields and only the last tab will contain the submit button. Other tabs will contain a "next" button that will only open the next tab. There could be a possible problem with the number of fields - You can send only limited amount of fields through POST and even more limited amount of fields through GET (sorry, don't know the numbers). Then after submit is invoked a validation takes place and then You can just fill the DB tables...
2. Create a form for each step. Create a model that will store the data. Each step will submit and only store the data into that model (except the last step - this will also invoke validation of inserted data) - while model will be saved within session. When validation fails You will redirect user to the first invalid step, display a message at what steps the data is invalid (also visually make that steps invalid). If the validation is OK, take the model and fill the DB tables...

Cannot tell You how difficult will both ways be as I didn't do such thing using ZF... And hope never will have to.

I would also consider talking to client and explain that validation only at the very last step is kinda foolish and user **un**-friendly...

Comment: Good ideas. The project manager here has already spoken to the client and told them that it's a bad idea but that's how they want it I'm afraid. We all agree that it's a horrendous idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'll split it up in a few sections:

**form handling**

You have two main choices here (no strong feelings one way or another):

1. Create the whole form in one page and use JavaScript (or a library such as jQuery) to move between the form sections; optionally you could do some client-side validation here as well.
2. Create one form per page and let PHP handle the carry-over, either by using sessions or keeping everything inside the form by using hidden input fields (I personally prefer sessions).

Handling the slight variations could be done by simply passing down the version in the first page and have your form change accordingly by adopting strategy pattern.

**final submission**

For validation you can use PHP's `filter` extension (shipped by default btw); it's pretty decent and extensible.

If validation fails, it's probably best to gather all errors and show them to the user (possibly with hyperlinks to jump to their respective sections) rather than only showing the first error; at each section you might mention the errors again for ease of use (users hate to jump back and forth).

Storing the whole form in your database is not much different in terms of variations than showing the form itself. Use strategy pattern again here.

Hope this covers most of it, let me know if you think I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

You are restricted by being unable to use an ORM or framework so you could take a look at serialization and storing objects as session objects.

Create a "Form" class with some properties specific to your forms and set these values after each form submission.

Comment: Yep, this is one way I considered doing it. The main issue with this is that I end up with an absolutely giant class with all kinds of custom validation rules for specific elements.